# Error when using axis with xpath query in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath

When using XPath expression "descendant::div" with selectNodes in IE i am getting an error "Expected token 'eof' found ':'". Is there something i am missing here, please help me get around this issue.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Comment: How are you using this? What is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting this error it means that the MSXML version in use is older than version 4.0 and thus default to the older value of XSLPattern that does not handle the XPath axis, e.g. 'descendant::'
Keshav´s solution should work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution somewhere on the web. To use complete xpath below property has to be set on the document object.

```
document.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
```